# Background-image: url() not loading my image

Tags: css, sass

I am trying to create a Hero banner where I would like to upload the image via `background-image: url()`.

However, my image doesn't appear to load despite being in the right folder. I have tried to switch it to the same folder as CSS too. Here I changed the url to moving_boxes.jpg

I have also tested another image. It's a jpg file.

```
.imgContainer {
background-image: url(../website_images/moving_boxes.jpg);
height: 70%;
background-position: center;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
position: relative;
}
```

where am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Can you please provide how your directory tree is structured?

Comment: Try removing things in your code. Like Position: relative. If that doesnt work, then your URL is not correct

Answer (score 0):

My guess based on not much context:

The url needs to point to where the image is hosted, not where it is relative to the source file. So the question is, where is your build process copying that asset to? If it's ending up in an `assets` folder at the top level of where your site is being served from, you would set the url to

```
url(/assets/moving_boxes.jpg)
```

Comment: Your answer doesn’t make much sense. Relative file paths in CSS are totally allowed: they’re relative to the stylesheet and not the document.

Comment: Yes they are supported in CSS. Sorry my answer assumes that the code we're looking at is referencing an image in a source folder, not a relative asset folder on the server. Maybe an incorrect assumption, just thought that might be the scenario